# What is the correct use of generics resolve this compilation error?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, generics

Reusing a previous example, imagine a zoo where newly arriving animals have to be "processed" by the Zookeeper (think of checking them in to the zoo).  Each animal's check-in process depends on its class taxonomy (Mammal, Bird, etc).

The processes differ because of the fundamental differences between the taxonomy classes - for example, Birds have wings, Mammals have teeth.  You might also have some shared bits of the process which are true for all animals, but I've omitted them here.

Here is the code:

Animal.java

```
public interface Animal {

    public AnimalProcessor<? extends Animal> getAnimalProcessor();
}
```

Mammal.java

```
public abstract class Mammal implements Animal {

    @Override
    public AnimalProcessor<Mammal> getAnimalProcessor() {

        return new MammalProcessor();
    } 

    // Specific to mammals
    public abstract int getToothCount();

}
```

Bird.java

```
public abstract class Bird implements Animal {

    @Override
    public AnimalProcessor<Bird> getAnimalProcessor() {

        return new BirdProcessor();
    }

    // Specific to birds
    public abstract float getWingspan();
}
```

AnimalProcessor.java

```
public interface AnimalProcessor<T extends Animal> {

    public void process(T critter);
}
```

MammalProcessor.java

```
public class MammalProcessor implements AnimalProcessor<Mammal> {

    @Override
    public void process(Mammal a) {
        System.out.println("Tooth count is " + a.getToothCount());
    }

}
```

BirdProcessor.java

```
public class BirdProcessor implements AnimalProcessor<Bird> {

    @Override
    public void process(Bird a) {
        System.out.print("Wingspan is " + a.getWingspan());
    }

}
```

Badger.java

```
public class Badger extends Mammal {

    @Override
    public int getToothCount() {
        return 40;
    }
}
```

Condor.java

```
public class Condor extends Bird {

    @Override
    public float getWingspan() {
        return 2.9f;
    }
}
```

ZooKeeper.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class ZooKeeper {

    public void processNewAnimals(List<Animal> newcomers)
    {
        for(Animal critter : newcomers)
        {
            AnimalProcessor<? extends Animal> ap = critter.getAnimalProcessor();

                        // This line has a compilation error!
            ap.process(critter);
        }
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ZooKeeper keeper = new ZooKeeper();

        List<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<Animal>();

        animals.add(new Badger());
        animals.add(new Condor());

        keeper.processNewAnimals(animals);

    }
}
```

There are no warnings anywhere, but **ap.process(critter)** cannot compile.
I know this is because `AnimalProcessor<Bird>` is *not* of type `AnimalProcessor<Animal>` but I cannot see how resolve the issue.  The call to `<T extends Animal>` `getAnimalProcessor()` will return a suitable `AnimalProcessor<T extends Animal>`, but I cannot express this in the code.

Perhaps I should not be pulling the AnimalProcessor out in the first place?

The goal is, of course, to be able to add `Reptile`, without changing the core.

Comment: Why is Animal an interface instead of an abstract class?  An interface should be some kind of shared behavior.

Comment: I take your point, and I have changed it in my code - but the compilation error remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public interface Animal<THIS extends Animal<THIS>> {
    AnimalProcessor<THIS> getAnimalProcessor();
}
public abstract class Mammal implements Animal<Mammal> {
```

A little like `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`.

It may be a better idea to remove the method.

Comment: I don't believe I've seen this approach before?  Does it have a name?

Comment: Sorry, remove which method? getAnimalProcessor()?  How would you make the rest of the code function in this case?

Comment: I should point out that I deliberately added the getAnimalProcessor method in order to tie together the two parallel inheritance hierarchies (Animal vs AnimalProcessor).

Comment: In my ideal world, I would not make the Animal know anything about how it is going to get processed... that way I can reuse my animals on Zoo, Farm, or ColouringBook, without having polluting code brought across.

Comment: @pjm56 As is you could just replace `getAnimalProcessor` with `process`. If you don't want `Animal`s to know about `AnimalProcessor`s, when you construct `Animal` package it in another object with the relevant `AnimalProcessor`.

Comment: thank you for this. Please could you give an example of how I would modify the other classes to make this work?  I have tried to replace getAnimalProcessor with process, but at the moment I am chasing generics errors around my IDE :(

Comment: Actually, I might not need the generics anymore. If I get stuck I will come back to you. Please don't worry about providing an example yet.

Comment: @newacct No, I don't think you can specify `getAnimalProcessor` if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

AnimalProcessor.java :

```
public interface AnimalProcessor<T extends Animal> {
    public void process(Animal critter);
}
```

MammalProcessor.java

```
public class MammalProcessor implements AnimalProcessor<Mammal> {
    @Override
    public void process(Animal a) {
        System.out.println("Tooth count is " + ((Mammal)a).getToothCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Iga - I can see this would work, but was hoping that I could use generics cleverly to avoid the downcast.  I think the fundamental reason you cannot dodge this is that the getAnimalProcessor method lets you pull out the processor of one animal, and potentially use it with any other Animal (which may be the wrong subtype). Perhaps it is impossible to 'square this circle' without using casts assertively in places where you are certain types will match.  Any style advice on casts like this?